# Flutter Project does not start

Tags: flutter, dart

When I want to start my project the following message appears

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
```

Then Google Chrome starts but it doesn't show anything except a white screen.

I have already reinstalled flutter, Dart SDK and VS Code.

**Flutter Doctor:**

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052], locale de-DE)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)

[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)

[√] Connected device (2 available)
```

Comment: Do you want to debug on Chrome or on Emulator/real-device?

Comment: Do you have any errors in console when running the project?

Comment: @Muhammet on Chrome, its a flutter web app.

Comment: @KirillBubochkin No nothing.

Comment: I had a similar problem with web app on 2.0 version because of http package which must be different for web, did you try android version.